# JAVA_HOME: COMMAND NOT FOUND

Tags: 18.04, java

I know my question is not new but I've tried every solution I could come across but nothing worked.
My system is ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, I keep getting this everytime I opened the terminal:

```
JAVA_HOME: COMMAND NOT FOUND
```

Even though I did fix the path in the /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java, I still get the same error, I tried to install Gradle but I couldn't because of it.
So I uninstall java and reinstall it again and now when I try to modify the path when I open the java file I get a garbage file.
Any idea how this can be fixed?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You probably have a syntax error in one of your shell startup files - for example, `JAVA_HOME = something` (with whitespace around the assignment) instead of `JAVA_HOME=something`

Comment: @steeldriver like I said when I open the file that contains that path I couldn't read anything it was all garbage.

Comment: @karel no it is not, because I tried to do that but the original file is unreadable